# Add extra node in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to modify an xml and to add an extra node in it . So far I am able to add this node but I need a little tweak.

My sample XML

```
<Search Name="Test2" ProjTypeID="107">
<CritGroup CritGroupID="1" >
    <Crit CritID="205"/>
    <Crit CritID="208"/>
</CritGroup></Search>
```

I am able to add the extra node but I need to add it as the existing "Crit" Node format(Where there is no closing "Crit" instead /> is used). But I ended up with below output.

```
<Search Name="Test2" ProjTypeID="107">
<CritGroup CritGroupID="1" >
    <Crit>CritID="206"</Crit>
    <Crit CritID="205"/>
    <Crit CritID="208"/>
</CritGroup> </Search>
```

I have used below code

```
            XmlNode newNode = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Crit", "");
            newNode.InnerText = "CritID=\"206\" ";

            XmlNode CritGroupNode = xmlDoc["Search"]["CritGroup"];
            XmlElement groups = CritGroupNode["CritGroup"];
            CritGroupNode.InsertAfter(newNode, groups);
```

Also is there any way to put the new node at the last ! For now its getting added as first? Thanks for reading and your help !

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. A root node is missing.

Comment: It is better to use LINQ to XML, instead of antiquated XML API (circa 2002 - 2006).

Comment: `<Crit>CritID="205"</Crit>` isn't equivalent to `<Crit CritID="205"/>`. The way to set attributes in XML is with other elements. The closest thing to `<Crit CritID="205"/>` would be `<Crit><CritID>"205"</CritID></Crit>`. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy via LINQ to XML.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Search Name='Test2' ProjTypeID='107'>
            <CritGroup CritGroupID='1'>
                <Crit CritID='205'/>
                <Crit CritID='208'/>
            </CritGroup>
        </Search>");
    xdoc.Dump("Before");

    XElement CritGroup = xdoc.Descendants("CritGroup")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("CritGroupID").Value == "1").FirstOrDefault();
    
    CritGroup.Add(new XElement("Crit",
        new XAttribute("CritID","206"),
        new XAttribute("RelID","280"),
        new XAttribute("CompValue","11")));
    
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
}
```

**Output**

```
<Search Name="Test2" ProjTypeID="107">
  <CritGroup CritGroupID="1">
    <Crit CritID="205" />
    <Crit CritID="208" />
    <Crit CritID="206" RelID="280" CompValue="11" />
  </CritGroup>
</Search>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer could you please let me know how to add more items along with CritID . Some thing like <Crit CritID="206" RelID="280" CompValue="11" CompValueHuman="Yes" AndOr="AND" TextBoxName="" /> . Thanks !.

Comment: I updated the answer. LINQ to XML makes it very easy. You can add as many as needed XML attributes.

Comment: My requirement is little more tweaky now and I want to add new element as a second element if at all any element exist with CritID=205.

Comment: Please post a brand new question, and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
    XmlElement newElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Crit");
    newElement.SetAttribute("CritId", "204");

    XmlNode CritGroupNode = xmlDoc["Search"]["CritGroup"];
    XmlElement groups = CritGroupNode["CritGroup"];
    CritGroupNode.InsertAfter(newElement, groups);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the `XDocument` solution in the other answer, but if that is not an option, this will insert a new `Crit` element last.

```cs
XmlElement newNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Crit");
newNode.SetAttribute("CritID", "206");

XmlNode CritGroupNode = xmlDoc["Search"]["CritGroup"];
CritGroupNode.InsertAfter(newNode, CritGroupNode.LastChild);
```